# Доступ из сервиса к классу с массивом строк

Tags: java, android, service, mediaplayer

У меня есть класс:

```
class Sounds {

private int sound_value;

static final Sounds[] mSound = {
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound1),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound2),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound3),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound4),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound5),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound6),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound7),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound8),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound9),
        new Sounds(R.raw.sound10),
};

private Sounds(int sound_value) {
    this.sound_value = sound_value;
}

int getSound_value() {
    return sound_value;
}
}
```

И есть сервис в методе onCreate которого:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {

    handler = new Handler();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);

    if (audioProgress != null) {
        length = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        audioProgress.setMax(length);
        handler.postDelayed(updateTimeTask, 1000);
        audioProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    super.onCreate();
}
```

У меня есть задача передать массив из класса Sound в MediaPlayer, который создается в сервисе, чтобы в соответствии с прокрученным фрагментом воспроизводился соответствующий медиа файл. Номер выбранного фрагмента получаю в методе onCreate класса фрагмента:

```
sectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Не очень понятно в чем именно вопрос. Если просто получить массив из сервиса, то сделайте его публичным полем и обращайтесь через `Sounds.mSound`. Только непонятно, к чему тут ещё какой-то фрагмент в конце вопроса. И почему он прокрученный.

Comment: У медиа плеера сейчас (this, R.raw.sound1); а мне нужно передать туда длину массива строк из класса Sound, а в самом приложении у меня реализован ViewPager, в котором используется один класс и макет. И прокручивая ViewPager в один и тот же макет загружаются разные данные. И вот при прокрутке я получаю номер фрагмента, и когда например номер фрагмента равен 5 или другому числу, то мне нужно чтобы сервис распознавал номер фрагмента и в соответствии с номером активного фрагмента выдавал трек из класса Sound

Comment: Если правильно понял что нужно, то когда получаете номер фрагмента, делайте `startService(intent)`, с номером фрагмента в этом `intent`. В сервисе будет вызван метод `onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` с этим интентом. Достаёте из него номер и получаете по нему нужный трек из `Sound`.

Comment: Теоретически понимаю, с вызовом сервиса через  putExtra передаю номер текущего фрагмента, и получаю его таким образом `int soundNumber = (int) intent.getExtras().get(NUMSOUND);` выдает ошибку `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`, ладно, буду копаться, примерное направление понял.

Comment: У интента есть метод `intent.getIntExtra(NUMSOUND, 0)`. И не нужно будет кастить. А какую ошибку-то получаете?

Comment: Исправил как вы сказали, работает, позицию получаю по крайне мере, теперь последний вопрос, плеер создается в методе `onCreate`, а позицию номера фрагмента получаю в `onStartCommand`, каким образом её в метод `onCreate`?. В любом случае основную проблему решил, можете вывести в ответ соединив ваши ответы, отмечу как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передать позицию текущего фрагмента в сервис можно с помощью метода `startService`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
intent.putExtra(NUMSOUND, position);
startService(intent);
```

В сервисе будет вызван метод `onStartCommand` с этим интентом. Из него мы получаем позицию и по позиции берём нужный трек:

```
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int position = intent.getIntExtra(NUMSOUND, 0);
    int soundRes = Sounds.mSound[position];  // у mSound должен быть необходимый модификатор доступа

    mp.release();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundRes);
    ...
}
```

Comment: "у mSound должен быть необходимый модификатор доступа" - можно пример?

Comment: У вас он не указан, то есть используется `default`. Если класс сервиса и класс `Sound` будут лежать в разных пакетах, то доступа к полю у вас не будет. [Модификаторы доступа в Java](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.3.php)

Comment: В одном пакете все классы